# Why can't python find scipy after a pip install?

Tags: macos, homebrew, python

I'm using pip to install python packages on macOS Sierra. When I pip install scipy and try to import it, python can't find the module. However when I pip install numpy and do the same thing, it seems to work. What's going wrong?

Comment: Can you post the exact `pip install` commands you used, and the exact Python code you're using to try to import them? Also can you post your PATH environment variable?

Comment: Hi @Steve 
It's nothing at all fancy to install I typed in the command prompt
`pip install scipy`
Then I opened up python2.7 and imported scipy to see if it worked like so
`python`
`import scipy`
and an import error arose
$PATH = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin

Comment: I'm about to post a similar question.  Apparently if a module already exists in the directories in sys.path, trying to install a different version with pip won't override what's there.  But if you install a module that is not included in Apple's stock Python install, it will be seen without trouble.